# Create empirical cumulative distribution function (CDF) and then use the CDF to find probabilities

Tags: excel, probability, cdf

I have a set of observed data and created an empirical cumulative distribution using Excel. I want to use this CDF to find probabilities like `P(x < X)` or `P (X1 < x < X2 )`.

The way I created the CDF is to arrange the data in ascending order and then create a column next to it with the probabilities:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsXhD.png]

I have 4,121 records and the sample here is for four records. Once I have this calculation done, the curve is plotted using xy scatter plot for `Data` in the x-axis and `Probability` in the y-axis. This is how I created the CDF.

How can I find probability below 2.5, `P(x<=2.5)`, or `P( 970 < x < 980 )`?

I hope there is an easy way because I will have hundreds of probabilities to find.

Comment: I am not too familiar with probabilities, but are you looking for something like the countif function?  For example, =COUNTIF(A2:A500, "<2.5")/(499-COUNTBLANK(A2:A500)

Comment: No I am looking for something to lookup for a value closest to the 2.5 for instance and then maybe interpolate for the probability.

In the picuture for instance, I know that 2.08 has a probability of 0.000727979  and 2.71 has a probability of 0.000970638.. Therefore, the probability of 2.5 must be somewhere between 0.000727979 and 0.000970638.  I know how to calculate this by hand, but if I have a huge set of probabilities that I need to find then this method is time consuming.

Comment: Can you tell us how you are doing it by hand?